# setting stdin to nonblocking affects ansi control sequence output

Tags: c, terminal, colors, ansi-escape

I am trying to draw a black box on terminal at top left corner with stdin nonblocking mode turned on. The black box has size 10 cols and 5 rows. I am using the following code to draw it.

```c
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    char s[] = "\e[1;1H\e[1;1H\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀";
    // char s1[] = "\e[1;1H\e[1;1H▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E";

    write(1, s, sizeof(s)-1);
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

However what I get is an incomplete box:

```
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
```

The printed string is produced by inserting `\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m` before each half block character.

What I tried didn't work are

- using different shell
- using different terminal emulators (Alacritty, Terminal.app, iTerm2)

What I tried that worked but not what I wanted

- printing in blocking mode
- remove code that changes color (`\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m`)
- changing half block character to normal printable ASCII character

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: I get a black box on konsole. Could be your shell prompt is removing characters. What happens when you add a sleep before `return 0`.

Comment: Still the same incomplete black box on alacritty.

Comment: So, did you check what `write` returns? Since it's non-blocking I think there's a higher probability that it writes fewer bytes than requested.  Why don't you want to print in blocking mode? Sidenote: `\e` is not a standard escape sequence. `\033` would be ESC.

Comment: `write` returns 1024 and `s` as length 1075. Also I can't print the return value of `write` to stdout. I had to write it to a file.

Comment: Ok, then that's the explanation.  You need to write the rest of the bytes until all 1075 have been written.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out `write` is not writing all data to stdout. Use a while loop to write all data to stdout.

```c
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main() {
    int flags = fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);

    char s[] = "\e[1;1H\e[1;1H\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[E\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀\e[38;5;0m\e[48;5;0m▀";
    // char s[] = "\e[1;1H\e[1;1H▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀\e[E";

    int i = 0;
    while (sizeof(s) - i > 0) {
        int l = write(1, s + i, sizeof(s) - i);
        if (l == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        i += l;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should also check if `write` returns -1 meaning an error has occurred. For non-blocking writes, you should at least expect to get return values of `-1` with `errno` set to  `EAGAIN` (or either `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` when writing to a socket).